# Error while running caret with C5.0

Tags: r, cross-validation, r-caret

I am trying code given in caret vignette and applying it on my data [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzRIG3kN-8Z9fmpXTW5YTGo3ZFpBVUZVU2I4UHdDMW02cXAxdVBqbnkxeWptUmRTd1FmZVE&usp=sharing).
I am using this code to evaluate C5.0 with 10-fold cross validation and ROC metric on my data:

```
tuned <- train (training, class, method="C5.0", tuneLength=11, tuneGrid=expand.grid(.model="tree",.trials=c(1:100),.winnow=FALSE),trC=trainCont‌​rol(method="repeatedcv",repeats=5,summaryFunction=twoClassSummary,classProbs=TRUE), metric="ROC")
```

Here, `training` is training data without class label and `class` is respective class label.

However I got this error:

> Error in evalSummaryFunction(y, wts = weights, ctrl = trControl, lev =
>   classLevels, : train()'s use of ROC codes requires class
>   probabilities. See the classProbs option of trainControl()

Can someone point out where am I wrong?

Comment: See my answer [here][1] to help with the "`something is wrong; all the ROC metric values are missing`" error you're having. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31467092/1710632

Answer (score 0):

Use `trControl` instead of `trC`. Also, you don't need periods in front of the tuning parameter names anymore.

Comment: I have tried it, now I am getting this **Something is wrong; all the ROC metric values are missing: Error in train.default(train, label, method = "C5.0", tuneLength = 10,  : 
  Stopping** and few warning messages also, saying **At least one of the class levels are not valid R variables names;** and **There were missing values in resampled performance measures.**