# Something is wrong; all the ROC metric values are missing:

Tags: r, r-caret

I'm training a model in R with the caret package:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 3,  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

logitBoostFit <- train(LoanStatus~., credit, method = "LogitBoost", family=binomial, preProcess=c("center", "scale", "pca"), 
    trControl = ctrl)
```

I'm getting the following warnings:

```
Warning message:
In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...): The metric "Accuracy" was not in the result set. ROC will be used instead.Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo, : There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
Something is wrong; all the ROC metric values are missing:
      ROC           Sens              Spec       
 Min.   : NA   Min.   :0.03496   Min.   :0.9747  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.:0.03919   1st Qu.:0.9758  
 Median : NA   Median :0.04343   Median :0.9770  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :0.04349   Mean   :0.9779  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.:0.04776   3rd Qu.:0.9795  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   :0.05210   Max.   :0.9821  
 NA's   :3                                       
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...): Stopping
```

I installed the pROC package:

```
install.packages("pROC", repos="http://cran.rstudio.com/")
library(pROC)
Type 'citation("pROC")' for a citation.

Attaching package: ‘pROC’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    cov, smooth, var
```

Here's the data:

```
str(credit)
'data.frame':   8580 obs. of  45 variables:
 $ ListingCategory            : int  1 7 3 1 1 7 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ IncomeRange                : int  3 4 6 4 4 3 3 4 3 3 ...
 $ StatedMonthlyIncome        : num  2583 4326 10500 4167 5667 ...
 $ IncomeVerifiable           : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE ...
 $ DTIwProsperLoan            : num  1.8e-01 2.0e-01 1.7e-01 1.0e+06 1.8e-01 4.4e-01 2.2e-01 2.0e-01 2.0e-01 3.1e-01 ...
 $ EmploymentStatusDescription: Factor w/ 7 levels "Employed","Full-time",..: 1 4 1 7 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Occupation                 : Factor w/ 65 levels "","Accountant/CPA",..: 37 37 20 14 43 58 48 37 37 37 ...
 $ MonthsEmployed             : int  4 44 159 67 26 16 209 147 24 9 ...
 $ BorrowerState              : Factor w/ 48 levels "AK","AL","AR",..: 22 32 5 5 14 28 4 10 10 34 ...
 $ BorrowerCity               : Factor w/ 3089 levels "AARONSBURG","ABERDEEN",..: 1737 3059 2488 654 482 719 895 1699 2747 1903 ...
 $ BorrowerMetropolitanArea   : Factor w/ 1 level "(Not Implemented)": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ LenderIndicator            : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ GroupIndicator             : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ GroupName                  : Factor w/ 83 levels "","00 Used Car Loans",..: 1 1 1 47 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ ChannelCode                : int  90000 90000 90000 80000 40000 40000 90000 90000 80000 90000 ...
 $ AmountParticipation        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ MonthlyDebt                : int  247 785 1631 817 644 1524 427 817 654 749 ...
 $ CurrentDelinquencies       : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ DelinquenciesLast7Years    : int  0 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ PublicRecordsLast10Years   : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 ...
 $ PublicRecordsLast12Months  : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ FirstRecordedCreditLine    : Factor w/ 4719 levels "1/1/00 0:00",..: 3032 2673 1197 2541 4698 4345 3150 925 4452 2358 ...
 $ CreditLinesLast7Years      : int  53 30 36 26 7 22 15 20 34 32 ...
 $ InquiriesLast6Months       : int  2 8 5 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 ...
 $ AmountDelinquent           : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 63 0 15 ...
 $ CurrentCreditLines         : int  10 10 18 10 4 11 6 10 7 8 ...
 $ OpenCreditLines            : int  9 10 15 8 3 8 5 7 7 8 ...
 $ BankcardUtilization        : num  0.26 0.69 0.94 0.69 0.81 0.38 0.55 0.24 0.03 0 ...
 $ TotalOpenRevolvingAccounts : int  9 7 12 10 3 5 4 5 4 6 ...
 $ InstallmentBalance         : int  48648 14827 0 0 0 30916 0 21619 41340 15447 ...
 $ RealEstateBalance          : int  0 0 577745 0 0 0 191296 0 0 126039 ...
 $ RevolvingBalance           : int  5265 9967 94966 50511 37871 22463 19550 2436 1223 3236 ...
 $ RealEstatePayment          : int  0 0 4159 0 0 0 1303 0 0 1279 ...
 $ RevolvingAvailablePercent  : int  78 52 36 45 18 61 44 74 96 76 ...
 $ TotalInquiries             : int  8 11 15 2 0 0 1 7 1 1 ...
 $ TotalTradeItems            : int  53 30 36 26 7 22 15 20 34 32 ...
 $ SatisfactoryAccounts       : int  52 23 36 26 7 19 15 18 34 29 ...
 $ NowDelinquentDerog         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 ...
 $ WasDelinquentDerog         : int  1 7 0 0 0 3 0 1 0 2 ...
 $ OldestTradeOpenDate        : int  5092001 5011977 12011984 4272000 9081993 9122000 6161987 11181999 9191990 4132000 ...
 $ DelinquenciesOver30Days    : int  0 6 0 0 0 13 0 2 0 2 ...
 $ DelinquenciesOver60Days    : int  0 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ DelinquenciesOver90Days    : int  0 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ IsHomeowner                : logi  FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
 $ LoanStatus                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 .`..
```

summary(credit)
 ListingCategory   IncomeRange    StatedMonthlyIncome IncomeVerifiable
 Min.   : 0.000   Min.   :1.000   Min.   :     0      Mode :logical
 1st Qu.: 1.000   1st Qu.:3.000   1st Qu.:  3167      FALSE:784
 Median : 2.000   Median :4.000   Median :  4750      TRUE :7796
 Mean   : 4.997   Mean   :4.089   Mean   :  5755      NA's :0
 3rd Qu.: 7.000   3rd Qu.:5.000   3rd Qu.:  7083
 Max.   :20.000   Max.   :7.000   Max.   :250000

DTIwProsperLoan     EmploymentStatusDescription MonthsEmployed
 Min.   :      0.0   Employed     :7182          Min.   :-23.00
 1st Qu.:      0.1   Full-time    : 416          1st Qu.: 26.00
 Median :      0.2   Not employed : 122          Median : 68.00
 Mean   :  91609.4   Other        : 475          Mean   : 97.44
 3rd Qu.:      0.3   Part-time    :   7          3rd Qu.:139.00
 Max.   :1000000.0   Retired      :  32          Max.   :755.00
                     Self-employed: 346          NA's   :5
 BorrowerState  LenderIndicator   GroupIndicator   ChannelCode
 CA     :1056   Min.   :0.00000   Mode :logical   Min.   :40000
 FL     : 608   1st Qu.:0.00000   FALSE:8325      1st Qu.:80000
 NY     : 574   Median :0.00000   TRUE :255       Median :80000
 TX     : 532   Mean   :0.09196   NA's :0         Mean   :77196
 IL     : 443   3rd Qu.:0.00000                   3rd Qu.:90000
 GA     : 343   Max.   :1.00000                   Max.   :90000
 (Other):5024
  MonthlyDebt      CurrentDelinquencies DelinquenciesLast7Years
 Min.   :    0.0   Min.   : 0.0000      Min.   : 0.000
 1st Qu.:  364.0   1st Qu.: 0.0000      1st Qu.: 0.000
 Median :  708.0   Median : 0.0000      Median : 0.000
 Mean   :  885.5   Mean   : 0.4119      Mean   : 4.009
 3rd Qu.: 1205.2   3rd Qu.: 0.0000      3rd Qu.: 3.000
 Max.   :30213.0   Max.   :21.0000      Max.   :99.000

PublicRecordsLast10Years PublicRecordsLast12Months CreditLinesLast7Years
 Min.   : 0.0000          Min.   :0.00000           Min.   :  2.0
 1st Qu.: 0.0000          1st Qu.:0.00000           1st Qu.: 16.0
 Median : 0.0000          Median :0.00000           Median : 24.0
 Mean   : 0.2809          Mean   :0.01364           Mean   : 26.1
 3rd Qu.: 0.0000          3rd Qu.:0.00000           3rd Qu.: 34.0
 Max.   :11.0000          Max.   :4.00000           Max.   :115.0

InquiriesLast6Months AmountDelinquent CurrentCreditLines OpenCreditLines 
 Min.   : 0.0000      Min.   :     0   Min.   : 0.000     Min.   : 0.000
 1st Qu.: 0.0000      1st Qu.:     0   1st Qu.: 5.000     1st Qu.: 5.000
 Median : 1.0000      Median :     0   Median : 9.000     Median : 8.000
 Mean   : 0.9994      Mean   :  1195   Mean   : 9.345     Mean   : 8.306
 3rd Qu.: 1.0000      3rd Qu.:     0   3rd Qu.:12.000     3rd Qu.:11.000
 Max.   :15.0000      Max.   :179158   Max.   :54.000     Max.   :42.000

BankcardUtilization TotalOpenRevolvingAccounts InstallmentBalance
 Min.   :0.0000      Min.   : 0.000             Min.   :     0
 1st Qu.:0.2500      1st Qu.: 3.000             1st Qu.:  3338
 Median :0.5400      Median : 6.000             Median : 14453
 Mean   :0.5182      Mean   : 6.441             Mean   : 24900
 3rd Qu.:0.7900      3rd Qu.: 9.000             3rd Qu.: 32238
 Max.   :2.2300      Max.   :44.000             Max.   :739371
                                                NA's   :328
 RealEstateBalance RevolvingBalance RealEstatePayment RevolvingAvailablePercent
 Min.   :      0   Min.   :     0   Min.   :    0.0   Min.   :  0.00
 1st Qu.:      0   1st Qu.:  2799   1st Qu.:    0.0   1st Qu.: 29.00
 Median :  26154   Median :  8784   Median :  346.5   Median : 52.00
 Mean   : 109306   Mean   : 19555   Mean   :  830.5   Mean   : 51.46
 3rd Qu.: 176542   3rd Qu.: 21110   3rd Qu.: 1382.2   3rd Qu.: 75.00
 Max.   :1938421   Max.   :695648   Max.   :13651.0   Max.   :100.00

TotalInquiries  TotalTradeItems SatisfactoryAccounts NowDelinquentDerog
 Min.   : 0.00   Min.   :  2.0   Min.   :  1.00       Min.   : 0.0000
 1st Qu.: 2.00   1st Qu.: 16.0   1st Qu.: 14.00       1st Qu.: 0.0000
 Median : 3.00   Median : 24.0   Median : 21.00       Median : 0.0000
 Mean   : 3.91   Mean   : 26.1   Mean   : 23.34       Mean   : 0.4119
 3rd Qu.: 5.00   3rd Qu.: 34.0   3rd Qu.: 30.25       3rd Qu.: 0.0000
 Max.   :36.00   Max.   :115.0   Max.   :113.00       Max.   :21.0000

WasDelinquentDerog OldestTradeOpenDate DelinquenciesOver30Days
 Min.   : 0.000     Min.   : 1011957    Min.   : 0.000
 1st Qu.: 0.000     1st Qu.: 4101996    1st Qu.: 0.000
 Median : 1.000     Median : 7191993    Median : 1.000
 Mean   : 2.343     Mean   : 6934230    Mean   : 4.332
 3rd Qu.: 3.000     3rd Qu.:10011990    3rd Qu.: 5.000
 Max.   :32.000     Max.   :12312004    Max.   :99.000

DelinquenciesOver60Days DelinquenciesOver90Days IsHomeowner     LoanStatus
 Min.   : 0.000          Min.   : 0.000          Mode :logical   0:1518
 1st Qu.: 0.000          1st Qu.: 0.000          FALSE:4264      1:7062
 Median : 0.000          Median : 0.000          TRUE :4316
 Mean   : 1.908          Mean   : 4.009          NA's :0
 3rd Qu.: 2.000          3rd Qu.: 3.000
 Max.   :73.000          Max.   :99.000

I didn't find any missing values:

```
try(na.fail(credit))

dput(head(credit,4))

structure(list(ListingCategory = c(1L, 7L, 3L, 1L), IncomeRange = c(3L, 
4L, 6L, 4L), StatedMonthlyIncome = c(2583.3333, 4326, 10500, 
4166.6667), IncomeVerifiable = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE), DTIwProsperLoan = c(0.18, 
0.2, 0.17, 1e+06), EmploymentStatusDescription = structure(c(1L, 
4L, 1L, 7L), .Label = c("Employed", "Full-time", "Not employed", 
"Other", "Part-time", "Retired", "Self-employed"), class = "factor"), 
    MonthsEmployed = c(4L, 44L, 159L, 67L), BorrowerState = structure(c(22L, 
    32L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("AK", "AL", "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", 
    "CT", "DC", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "KS", 
    "KY", "LA", "MA", "MD", "MI", "MN", "MO", "MS", "MT", "NC", 
    "NE", "NH", "NJ", "NM", "NV", "NY", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", 
    "RI", "SC", "SD", "TN", "TX", "UT", "VA", "VT", "WA", "WI", 
    "WV", "WY"), class = "factor"), LenderIndicator = c(0L, 0L, 
    0L, 1L), GroupIndicator = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE), ChannelCode = c(90000L, 
    90000L, 90000L, 80000L), MonthlyDebt = c(247L, 785L, 1631L, 
    817L), CurrentDelinquencies = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), DelinquenciesLast7Years = c(0L, 
    10L, 0L, 0L), PublicRecordsLast10Years = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L
    ), PublicRecordsLast12Months = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CreditLinesLast7Years = c(53L, 
    30L, 36L, 26L), InquiriesLast6Months = c(2L, 8L, 5L, 0L), 
    AmountDelinquent = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), CurrentCreditLines = c(10L, 
    10L, 18L, 10L), OpenCreditLines = c(9L, 10L, 15L, 8L), BankcardUtilization = c(0.26, 
    0.69, 0.94, 0.69), TotalOpenRevolvingAccounts = c(9L, 7L, 
    12L, 10L), InstallmentBalance = c(48648L, 14827L, 0L, 0L), 
    RealEstateBalance = c(0L, 0L, 577745L, 0L), RevolvingBalance = c(5265L, 
    9967L, 94966L, 50511L), RealEstatePayment = c(0L, 0L, 4159L, 
    0L), RevolvingAvailablePercent = c(78L, 52L, 36L, 45L), TotalInquiries = c(8L, 
    11L, 15L, 2L), TotalTradeItems = c(53L, 30L, 36L, 26L), SatisfactoryAccounts = c(52L, 
    23L, 36L, 26L), NowDelinquentDerog = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), WasDelinquentDerog = c(1L, 
    7L, 0L, 0L), OldestTradeOpenDate = c(5092001L, 5011977L, 
    12011984L, 4272000L), DelinquenciesOver30Days = c(0L, 6L, 
    0L, 0L), DelinquenciesOver60Days = c(0L, 4L, 0L, 0L), DelinquenciesOver90Days = c(0L, 
    10L, 0L, 0L), IsHomeowner = c(FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), 
    LoanStatus = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", 
    "1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ListingCategory", "IncomeRange", 
"StatedMonthlyIncome", "IncomeVerifiable", "DTIwProsperLoan", 
"EmploymentStatusDescription", "MonthsEmployed", "BorrowerState", 
"LenderIndicator", "GroupIndicator", "ChannelCode", "MonthlyDebt", 
"CurrentDelinquencies", "DelinquenciesLast7Years", "PublicRecordsLast10Years", 
"PublicRecordsLast12Months", "CreditLinesLast7Years", "InquiriesLast6Months", 
"AmountDelinquent", "CurrentCreditLines", "OpenCreditLines", 
"BankcardUtilization", "TotalOpenRevolvingAccounts", "InstallmentBalance", 
"RealEstateBalance", "RevolvingBalance", "RealEstatePayment", 
"RevolvingAvailablePercent", "TotalInquiries", "TotalTradeItems", 
"SatisfactoryAccounts", "NowDelinquentDerog", "WasDelinquentDerog", 
"OldestTradeOpenDate", "DelinquenciesOver30Days", "DelinquenciesOver60Days", 
"DelinquenciesOver90Days", "IsHomeowner", "LoanStatus"), row.names = c(NA, 
4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any ideas on what's wrong?

```
Warning message:
In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...): The metric "Accuracy" was not in the result set. ROC will be used instead.
# weights:  72 (71 variable)
initial  value 5144.538374 
iter  10 value 3540.667624
iter  20 value 3329.692768
iter  30 value 3279.191024
iter  40 value 3264.926986
iter  50 value 3259.276647
iter  60 value 3259.056261
final  value 3259.032668 
converged
# weights:  72 (71 variable)
initial  value 5144.538374 
iter  10 value 3540.774666
iter  20 value 3330.016829
iter  30 value 3279.545595
iter  40 value 3265.384385
iter  50 value 3259.499032
iter  60 value 3259.353010
final  value 3259.342601 
converged
# weights:  72 (71 variable)
initial  value 5144.538374 
iter  10 value 3540.667731
iter  20 value 3329.693092
iter  30 value 3279.191379
iter  40 value 3264.927427
iter  50 value 3259.276899
iter  60 value 3259.056561
final  value 3259.032978 
converged
# weights:  72 (71 variable)
initial  value 5144.538374 
iter  10 value 3528.401458
iter  20 value 3314.932958
iter  30 value 3264.117072
iter  40 value 3253.780051
iter  50 value 3253.368959
iter  60 value 3253.359047
final  value 3253.358819 
converged
# weights:  72 (71 variable)
initial  value 5144.538374 
iter  10 value 3528.508505
iter  20 value 3315.134599
iter  30 value 3265.021404
iter  40 value 3255.739021
iter  50 value 3253.817833
iter  60 value 3253.697180
final  value 3253.671003 
converged
# weights:  72 (71 variable)
initial  value 5144.538374 
iter  10 value 3528.401565
iter  20 value 3314.933160
iter  30 value 3264.117768
iter  40 value 3253.780539
iter  50 value 3253.369030
iter  60 value 3253.359358
final  value 3253.359133 
converged
# weights:  71 (70 variable)
initial  value 5145.231521 
iter  10 value 4680.326236
iter  20 value 4672.506024
iter  30 value 3662.998233
iter  40 value 3310.207744
iter  50 value 3252.983656
iter  60 value 3250.400275
iter  70 value 3250.339216
final  value 3250.332646 
converged
```

...    # weights:  72 (71 variable)
    initial  value 5144.538374 
    iter  10 value 4661.569290
    iter  20 value 4652.246624
    iter  30 value 3715.472355
    iter  40 value 3484.096833
    iter  50 value 3254.247424
    iter  60 value 3248.931841
    iter  70 value 3248.154679
    iter  80 value 3248.129089
    iter  80 value 3248.129085
    final  value 3248.128574 
    converged
    # weights:  72 (71 variable)
    initial  value 5144.538374 
    iter  10 value 4663.660886
    iter  20 value 4654.255466
    iter  30 value 3542.473235
    iter  40 value 3315.027437
    iter  50 value 3250.340679
    iter  60 value 3248.693378
    iter  70 value 3248.455840
    iter  80 value 3248.443345
    iter  80 value 3248.443325
    iter  80 value 3248.443325
    final  value 3248.443325 
    converged
    # weights:  72 (71 variable)
    initial  value 5144.538374 
    iter  10 value 4661.571382
    iter  20 value 4652.248711
    iter  30 value 4397.069608
    iter  40 value 3532.067046
    iter  50 value 3283.179445
    iter  60 value 3249.518694
    iter  70 value 3248.163057
    iter  80 value 3248.129552
    final  value 3248.128889 
    converged
    Warning message:
    In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo, : There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
    Something is wrong; all the ROC metric values are missing:
          ROC           Sens              Spec
     Min.   : NA   Min.   :0.01805   Min.   :0.9946
     1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.:0.01805   1st Qu.:0.9946
     Median : NA   Median :0.01805   Median :0.9946
     Mean   :NaN   Mean   :0.01805   Mean   :0.9946
     3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.:0.01805   3rd Qu.:0.9946
     Max.   : NA   Max.   :0.01805   Max.   :0.9946
     NA's   :3
    Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...): Stopping

summaryFunction = twoClassSummary appears to trigger the warning.
It happens here as well:

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

multinomSummaryFit <- train(LoanStatus~., credit, method = "multinom", family=binomial, 
    trControl = ctrl)

Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo, : There were missing values in resampled performance measures.
Something is wrong; all the ROC metric values are missing:
      ROC           Sens              Spec       
 Min.   : NA   Min.   :0.01919   Min.   :0.9941  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.:0.01988   1st Qu.:0.9942  
 Median : NA   Median :0.02056   Median :0.9943  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :0.02011   Mean   :0.9943  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.:0.02056   3rd Qu.:0.9943  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   :0.02057   Max.   :0.9944  
 NA's   :3                                       
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...): Stopping
```

Comment: To increase your changes on an answer, you may want to strip down your example to a more manageable size. In the process you'll either find the problem yourself or end up with a small dataset that you can post via `dput`. With the current description it may be hard to get past: check your data for NA, Inf and NaN. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Possibly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873989/caret-error-something-is-wrong-all-the-roc-metric-values-are-missing

Comment: Appended dput(head(credit,4))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to change class variable values from "0","1"  to e.g.  "A" , "B"  and try then.

Comment: Just - $ LoanStatus                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 .`..

Comment: yes.  Just change LoanStatus to have e.g. "A", "B" instead "0", "1". Keep in mind that you will have to deal with factor levels first but converting to character , do the conversion and transform back to factor should work.    I had a similar problem , it seems issue was that it tries to name column "0" and "1"  when calculating metrics and that's where error happens.

Comment: Ok.  I got further (see new warning and results appended).

Comment: Warning message:
In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo, : There were missing values in resampled performance measures.

Comment: This seems to be the problem - ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 3,  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

Answer (score 9):

Looking at the output of `summary(credit)`, I can see that there are `NA` values in at least two variables;

The variable `MonthsEmployed` has `5 NA` values:

```
MonthsEmployed 
Min.   :-23.00  
1st Qu.: 26.00  
Median : 68.00 
Mean   : 97.44  
3rd Qu.:139.00  
Max.   :755.00  
NA's   :5
```

and the variable `InstallmentBalance` has `328 NA` values.

```
InstallmentBalance
Min.   :     0  
1st Qu.:  3338       
Median : 14453       
Mean   : 24900       
3rd Qu.: 32238      
Max.   :739371    
NA's   :328
```

Try removing the rows with missing values (or temporary remove these two variables) and run the function again to see if this solves your problem.

Also, You need to add `metric = "ROC"` to the `train` function and `classProbs = TRUE` to `trainControl()` when you use `twoClassSummary`

```
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", 
                     repeats = 3, 
                     classProbs = TRUE,
                     summaryFunction = twoClassSummary) .
```

So, your call should be

```
multinomSummaryFit <- train(LoanStatus~., 
                            data = credit, 
                            method = "multinom", 
                            family=binomial, 
                            metric = "ROC",
                            trControl = ctrl)
```

Another important issue about your dataset, you need to carefully inspect variables' values and make sure that each value makes sense. For example, the `MonthsEmployed` variable has negative values. Logically, an employee has a positive number of months employed. Are these negative values wrong or do they mean something else! (for example a value of -23 means the person has not been employed for 23 month).

To answer your question regarding `confusionMatrix`:

Let's say your trained model is called `multinomSummaryFit`. In order to evaluate your model on the test dataset, you need to call `predict` method on the test dataset without `LoanStatus` (using the same variables you trained your model on), and then compare your model predictions to the actual value in `LoanStatus`. For example,

```
#let's say your test datafrme is called test
mymodel_pred <- predict(multinomSummaryFit, test[, names(test) != "LoanStatus"])
```

then use `confusionMatrix`:

```
confusionMatrix(data = mymodel_pred, 
                reference = test$LoanStatus, 
                positive = "Default")
```

If the test dataset does not have the `LoanStatus` column then you just use:

```
mymodel_pred <- predict(multinomSummaryFit, test)
```

but in this case, you have no way to evaluate your model on the test dataset if you do not know the actual response.

Remember, if you removed any variables from the training dataset, you need to remove them also from the test dataset before you call `predict`

Splitting the data to train and test using stratified sampling:

```
trainingRows <- createDataPartition(credit$LoanStatus, p = .70, list= FALSE)
train <- credit[trainingRows, ]
test <- credit[-trainingRows, ]
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that!  Do you know what this warning is about: ctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 3,  summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)  multinomSummaryFit <- train(LoanStatus~., credit, method = "multinom", family=binomial, 
    trControl = ctrl)  Warning message:
In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...): The metric "Accuracy" was not in the result set. ROC will be used instead.

Comment: Same problem after removing columns: MonthsEmployed & InstallmentBalance (no more negative values). E.g. "Something is wrong; all the ROC metric values are missing:"

Comment: It's running now ... so far, no complaints.  I had to add: classProbs = TRUE,

Comment: Oh yeah, you need to add `classProbs = TRUE` to `trainControl()`.

Comment: Cool!
Multinomial Regression 
8580 samples
  36 predictor
   2 classes: 'Default', 'NonDefault' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (10 fold, repeated 3 times) 
Summary of sample sizes: 7722, 7722, 7722, 7721, 7723, 7723, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  decay  ROC        Sens        Spec       ROC SD      Sens SD     Spec SD    
  0e+00  0.6522402  0.02195887  0.9931562  0.01985756  0.01274415  0.002999899
  1e-04  0.6519730  0.02195887  0.9930618  0.01967029  0.01274415  0.002864708
  1e-01  0.6523307  0.02217962  0.9933922  0.01992944  0.01367039  0.002815529

Comment: I have a training data file and a test data file.  The last column in the training file is: $ LoanStatus                 : Factor w/ 2 levels "Default","NonDefault": 2 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 ...  Does this column ALSO need to be in the test file and test dataframe?  (So the confusion matrix has the same number of levels)?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30002013/error-in-confusion-matrix-the-data-and-reference-factors-must-have-the-same-nu

Comment: See above my response to your question. Did I answer your question?

Comment: mymodel_pred <- predict(multinomSummaryFit, creditTesting[, names(creditTesting) != "LoanStatus"])
confusionMatrix(data = mymodel_pred, 
                reference = creditTesting$LoanStatus, 
                positive = "Default") Error in confusionMatrix.default(data = mymodel_pred, reference = creditTesting$LoanStatus, : the data cannot have more levels than the reference

Comment: Error in confusionMatrix.default(data = mymodel_pred, reference = creditTesting$LoanStatus, : the data cannot have more levels than the reference

Comment: How did you split the data to train and test datasets?, make sure when you split the data that both train and test datasets have all classes present. you can do this by using the caret package stratified sampling, see above.

Comment: The client sent me the training data and test data in two distinct files.  Should I concatenate these two file and split by line numbers?  I am concerned what is happening i) with preprocessing (e.g. scale, center, PCA) when files are separate, -vs- ii) combining training and test into one file.

Comment: Do you have `LoanStatus` variable in your test file?, if so use `table(creditTesting$LoanStatus)` to see the distribution of "Default","NonDefault" in your test file. I am guessing it has only one of them.

Comment: Also, can you use `head(mymodel_pred)` to see what your model is predicting.

Answer (score 1):

I got a similar issue on some data where I used the option "summaryFunction = twoClassSummary" to have some output performance metric and some data features had sd() equal to 1.

I solved the problem by keeping out the "twoClassSummary" and computing the performance metrics I required (e.g. ROC, CM) in a following step.