# How do you pull error information from caret train error in Rdotnet?

Tags: r, r.net

I tried to train a model in `RDotNet` and got this error:

```
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : Stopping
```

I ran the same script in `RStudio` and it added some more information:

Something is wrong; all the `ROC` metric values are missing:

```
     ROC           Sens          Spec    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :6     NA's   :6     NA's   :6
```

Does anyone where/how I can pull that information from the REngine when the exception above appears since it doesn't appear to be in the exception itself?  Thanks.

Comment: I have had experience with this and it is helpful lesson that many classification algorithms expect variables in `factor` class i.e. if you have numeric`classes=c(0,1)` , they need to be transformed to first as character , `classes=c("0","1")`  OR `classes=c("zero","one")` and finally , `classes=as.factor(classes)`. In short, target variable needs to be of class `factor` and unfortunately I could not locate this in documentation. See this for [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32551859/something-is-wrong-all-the-roc-metric-values-are-missing)

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't gotten that far yet :).  Unfortunately, that same error could come from multiple sources so I was hoping to have a way to figure out how to differentiate between them.  I figure if RStudio can do it, maybe I can too.  Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran across this while researching.  It's not a perfect solution, but this post should do the trick.  Using the withCallingHandlers function you can at least capture errors and warnings and review them later.

[How do I save warnings and errors as output from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948361/how-do-i-save-warnings-and-errors-as-output-from-a-function)